# parse remote pdf through tabula-extractor gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabula

I'm using a tabula-extractor gem to parse the pdf. My question is that is it possible that I can parse the remote pdf without downloading it

As per its documentation, 
https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor
we need to give pdf file path. I have to parse thousands of pdf files so it would be hectic to download all the pdf files.

Any solution to solve my above problem will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to process a file completely remotely, you will still need to download it.

However, it seems like one can still avoid saving it on the disk by extending the functionality of the gem.

Something in the lines of:

```
java_import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
java_import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardDecryptionMaterial

def openRemotePDF(pdf_link, password='')
  file = Faraday.get(pdf_link).body
  document = PDDocument.load(file)
  if document.isEncrypted
    sdm = StandardDecryptionMaterial.new(password)
    document.openProtection(sdm)
  end
  document
end

class RemoteObjectExtractor < Java::TechnologyTabula::ObjectExtractor
  def initialize(pdf_link, pages=[1], password='', options={})
    @pdf_link = pdf_link
    document = openRemotePDF(pdf_link, password)

    super(document)
  end
end
```

should work (I've adapted the code from the tabula-extractor gem). According to PDDocument [documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(byte[])) the load static method should allow for in-memory variables.

Notice the Java dependencies, so this will only work in jruby (which you probably already use).